# Modify String objects in a static array

Tags: java, arrays, string, list, object

I want to make a for-loop to add a letter to each string object in my list. I'm just not sure how to edit the objects in the list and not the actual list.

for instance, if I wanted to add "ing" to the end of each object in my list..

I feel like it's something simple, but I've been looking through oracle forever and haven't been able to figure it out if anyone can point me in the right direction?

I could use any kind of list really.. just anything that works.

I was thinking something like,

```
    String[] stringArray = tools.toArray(new String[0]);
            for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++)
            {
                stringArray[i] = stringArray[i].*part that would modify would go here*
            }
```

Comment: You can't modify Strings, so you need to use some other kind of object or modify list.

Comment: updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot edit a `String`. They are immutable. However, you can replace the entry in the list.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("load");
list.add("pull");

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
    list.set(i, list.get(i) + "ing");
```

You updated your question to specify a static array:

```
stringArray[i] = stringArray[i] + "ing";
```

The right side of the assignment is performing a String `concatenation` which can be done with the `+` operator in Java.

Comment: I think doing stringArray[i] = stringArray[i] + "ing"; will automatically replace the old reference with the one of the new String created for the concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use StringBuilder for this purpose.

```
public static void addIng(String[] arr) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sb.setLength(0);
        sb.append(arr[i] + "ing");
        arr[i] = sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable in java; they can't be modified once created.

Here it seems you have a few options; you can create a method that takes your list and returns a new list, by appending `'ing'` to the end of each string in the list.

Alternatively, if you need to keep a reference to the original list, you can loop over the contents of the list (ArrayList?) and pop each string out, create a new string with the appended `'ing'`, and replace in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("testing");
for(String s:list){
    s=s+"ing";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look below samples.

```
   //Java 8 code.
   List<String> oldList = Arrays.asList("a", "b");
   List<String> newList = oldList.stream().map(str -> new StringBuilder(str).append("ing").toString()).collect(Collectors.toList());
   System.out.println(oldList); // [a, b]
   System.out.println(newList); // [aing, bing]

   // Java 7 or below.
   List<String> oldList = Arrays.asList("a", "b");
   List<String> newList = new LinkedList<String>();
   for (String str : oldList) {
       newList.add(new StringBuilder(str).append("ing").toString());
   }
   System.out.println(oldList); // [a, b]
   System.out.println(newList); // [aing, bing]
```